# generate a .docx file with Template.docx

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am thinking about a .docx document generator. It's basically used as (it's a C# console application):

DocxGenerator.exe ATemplate.docx varsDefinations.txt

The ATemplate.docx will provide the basic template with some fields to be filled. And the varsDefinations.txt will provide these variables to fill the fields.

However, I don't know how to implement this at all. I've been searching about Open XML and other documents.
The obstacle for now is what the field I should use in this case.

For example, the ATemplate.docx might be like this:

Dear {Field1},

We are happy to tell you {Field2}.

Regards,
{Field3}

and in the varsDefinations.txt, I want to do like this:

Field1 = "Lovely people who answer my question"; Field2 = "that you are the best ever"; Field3 = "Payson";

Has anyone done something like this? (I am sure it's a yes! Since I received so many "I am sorry" letters.)

In summary, my question is:

1. What field I should use such that it can be treated as a variable
2. How to read the file with C# so that I can "detect" all the variable fields

Thank you so much in advance.

-------------------EDIT 1----------------------------

1. I've figured that i can use "mergefield" (answered question 1).
2. For question 2, this will work:
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38575/Fill-Mergefields-in-docx-Documents-without-Microso

this will help. This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Feature called [Word mail merge](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx)... If you want to implement something yourself it may be good idea to start with ability to read Word documents (check out "Word interop" or "OpenXML SDK"), come back with more concrete questions.

Comment: I agree with Alexei, you will want to lookup OpenXML SDK. This may also be a useful tool when working with OpenXML documents: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/450a00e3-5a7d-4776-be2c-8aa8cec2a75b. It's for Visual Studio 2010 though. I haven't found a version for 2012 or 2013.

Comment: Thank you! @NathanRenico I am checking OpenXML SDK

Comment: Hi @Payson, do you need any help on this question anymore? Good luck

Comment: @GuidoLeenders Thanks for asking. I am sorry for the late reply. I don't think so. As what I put under the EDIT 1. I've found a perfect project in the code project. But thanks anyway for asking. I am working on the EXCEL generator right now. Will add questions about that maybe later.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i would suggest you to keep a separator in between each information in your textfile.

i guess your text file( varsDefinations.txt) is like this. note i am keeping "-" as separator in between lines.

varsDefinations.txt looks like this :

```
 Lovely people who answer my question -
 that you are the best ever -
 Payson
```

Then here is the code which generates the word document as the specified destination. Here i am working with .doc file. You can replace this with .docx.

Here is the code as per your requirement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WordFileGeneratorFromTextFileConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string textfileName = "varsDefinations.txt";
                string wordfileName = "ATemplate.doc";
                string fileNameWithPath = @"C:\Quotations\" + wordfileName;

                CustomMessage aMesssage = new CustomMessage();

                //Reading from text file
                using (FileStream fs =
                    new FileStream(@"C:\Quotations\" + textfileName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

                    string temp = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] temparr = temp.Split('-');
                    for (int i = 0; i < temparr.Length;i++ )
                    {
                        string s = temparr[i];
                        if (s.Contains('\r'))
                        {
                            s = s.Replace('\r', ' ');
                        }
                        if (s.Contains('\n'))
                        {
                            s = s.Replace('\n', ' ');
                        }
                        temparr[i] = s;
                    }
                    if (temparr != null)
                    {
                        aMesssage.HeaderMessage = temparr[0];
                        aMesssage.MainMessage = temparr[1];
                        aMesssage.MessageSender = temparr[2];
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                }

                //Writing to word document
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWithPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                    sw.WriteLine(aMesssage.HeaderMessage);
                    sw.WriteLine(aMesssage.MainMessage);
                    sw.WriteLine(aMesssage.MessageSender);

                    sw.Close();
                }

                //Opening Word Document
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileNameWithPath);

            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex2.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    class CustomMessage
    {
        public string HeaderMessage { get; set; }
        public string MainMessage { get; set; }
        public string MessageSender { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kumarch1! in my question, I just gave an example. Actually, the variables in the txt may not in the exactly same order. Also the letter could be more complicated than this. Maybe there are hundreds of fields to be filled. Do you have an idea how to deal with this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider.

First check whether you want the template to be created from within Microsoft Word by non-IT personnel.

Secondly do you need multiple occurrences (a loop)?

If the template is to be created by IT-personnel, you can use the following approach:

- Create the template using Word.
- Open the XML in the zip.
- Word introduces a lot of small XML fragments everywhere and that can occur also WITHIN a variable name.
- Edit it such that your variable names chosen do not contain anymore a XML tag.
- Make sure your variable names chosen are not contained elsewhere, such as in a b64 encoded picture. Including a non-base64 character fixes that.
- In your console program open the resulting template docx and simply replace all occurrences.

If the template is to be created by non-IT personnel, the approach becomes more complex:

- Create the template using Word.
- Your console program should firs parse the XML, constructing the tree and a serialized version of the text (phase 1 parser).
- Take care of pictures separately since they can become very large and memory consuming.
- The XML tree and the serialized version you can feed into a second phase parser which is a normal text parser able to handle the variable names chosen. You might use a simple LALR parser using lex/yacc or ANTLR.
- In the parser replace variable names by their representative value.

When you add loops, you will need to make sure that you either handcraft the XML to avoid XML fragments being copied are unbalanced or create an algorithm that balances the XML to ensure the repeating elements together form valid XML.

Concerning your question: we've made similar software and maybe you find use for the naming we've used, such as $F{x}. The manual is located at http://www.invantive.com/en/doc/invantive-composition/Invantive.Producer.Composition.Word.en.pdf and syntax in section 1.6 and further on.

Comment: Thanks, Guido. I have no idea till now it's created by IT or non-IT personnel. I think maybe IT-personnel. I will think about this carefully. Thanks for your software you mentioned. However, I still have to do something on my own.

Comment: You are welcome. When you can influence the project, try to make sure that the template is maintained by IT-staff using notepad++ or alike. Saves you maybe hundreds of development hours.